# Integrating google analytics in webapp: not able to log user interactions

Tags: google-analytics

I have created a webapp using backbone.js and I am trying to integrate google analytics in it. The thing is script execution always stops at some point inside ga.js. The code where the execution stops is like this (beautified version) ...

```
var o = e == "_gat" ? K : e == "_gaq" ? Tc : K.p(e);
o[f].apply(o, b[d][ha](1))
```

minified version (line 21)

```
new ActiveXObject(d),e=c.GetVariable("$version")}catch(o){}e&&(e=e[w](" ")[1][w](","),e=e[0]+"."+e[1]+" r"+e[2])}b=e?e:"-"}Pc=b;
```

I am logging the events like this:

```
_gaq.push('_trackEvent', '[header] login', 'click');
```

I am seeing the code being stopped at the live above in Firebug script tab. If I disable the debugging the google analytics request is not made. The app works fine.

What could be going wrong here? Has anybody else encountered such problem.

**UPDATE**

It seems like the problem is not related to backbone.js. Even created the simplest of page like this gave the same problem. I checked the Net tab in Firebug - the `__utm.gif` does load. `ga.js` also loads successfully. But the pressing the button again gives the same break in execution.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XX-XXXXXX-XX']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function check() {
                alert("hi");
                _gaq.push('_trackEvent', 'check');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="abc" onclick="check();"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling _trackEvent wrong. Note that the first 2 parameters to _trackEvent are required and the last 2 optional. Also it should be inside brackets.

Check the [signature](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiEventTracking.html#_gat.GA_EventTracker_._trackEvent) of the function.

You're call should be

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '[header] login', 'click']);
```

and

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'check', 'something else']);
```